# How to organize data for a CMS that controls several websites?

Tags: info-visualisation, wireframe, sitemap

We are building a CMS that controls data for 3 different portals. These 3 portals are not the same although connected to each other. Think of it like there's a portal for **Renters**, portal for **Tenants**, and portal for **Agents** (just an example). These 3 portals may have different contents but they all have users, data lists, settings, etc. and they are all editable via **1 CMS**.

What is the best way to organize them in the CMS in such a way that it's easy for the **Master Admin** to navigate through?

Should I create the major division in the CMS...

By website / portal?

**Website 1:** Dashboard, Users, Data List, Analytics, etc.

**Website 2:** Dashboard, Users, Data List, Analytics, etc.

**Website 3:** Dashboard, Users, Data List, Analytics, etc.

Or by section name?

**Dashboard:** Website 1 Dashboard, Website 2 Dashboard, Website 3 Dashboard

**Users:** Website 1 Users, Website 2 Users, Website 3 Users

**Data List:** Website 1 Data List, Website 2 Data List, Website 3 Data List

Comment: What do you mean by “building a CMS”? Are you developing a competitor to Drupal, Sitecore, etc.? Building a solution that uses one of those tools? Building a custom CMS software just for managing these 3 portals?

Answer (score 1):

**Why not both view?**

I think that the view choice will be changed according to the goal of the super admin. You should focus on the **goal , tasks of the administrator**. Does admin searches based on the website or users? Why does admin need divided information? In order to complete xxxxx, which view makes more sense?

Try to make a list to show + and - of each clustering attempt.

From technical perspective, you can re-render the data without loading the page depending on your tech stack. There isn't a best view solution without having a bind to its content and context...

Answer (score 0):

The best way to organized information will be "the way human eye human eye perceive information"

Human eye perceive information in hierarchically, so i would make more sense, to take all together a third approach apart form section name and portal.

My approach will be to organization information based on user groups, as display below.

[image]